# Can't post data via Guzzle request to Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, api, post, guzzle

I'm having troubles posting data to my production Laravel controller to store a post request made with Guzzle from my local WAMP server. I can successfully return data with a get request, but posting data does not seem to work.  I have Oauth2 setup using Laravel Passport.

The following is my Guzzle post request from the WAMP server.

```php
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();

$response = $client->post('https://www.website.com/oauth/token', [
    'form_params' => [
        'client_id' => 99,
        'client_secret' => '***',
        'grant_type' => 'password',
        'username' => 'username@mail.com',
        'password' => 'password',
        'scope' => '*',
    ],
]);

$auth = json_decode((string) $response->getBody()->getContents());
$data = [
    'first_name' => 'Post', 'last_name' => 'Man',
    'email' => 'postman@mail.com', 'phone' => '0400000000',
    'country' => 'Internet', 'state' => 'HTTP'
];
$json_data = json_encode($data);

$header = array('Authorization' => 'Bearer '.$auth->access_token, 'Content-Type' => 'application/json');
$response = $client->post('https://www.website.com/api/store_data',
    ['body' => $json_data, 'headers' => $header]);

$stream = $response->getBody()->getContents();
dd($stream);
```

Returns:

```
"{"attributes":{},"request":{},"query":{},"server":{},"files":{},"cookies":{},"headers":{}}"
```

And when I try to store the data in my production controller nothing comes across in the request:

```php
$enquiry = new Enquiry;
$enquiry->first_name = $request->get('first_name');
$enquiry->last_name = $request->get('last_name');
....
$enquiry->save();
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$response->getBody()->getContents()`?

Comment: Are you refering to the line: $stream = $response->getBody()->getContents();

Comment: No, I'm referring to `$auth = json_decode(...)`.

Comment: For your request to get through you need to send the correct `Content-Type`. In this case it should be `application/json`

Comment: Updated header to include content-type, and added getContents() to $auth, still no luck.

Comment: Working now, think i had a page caching issue.

Answer (score 0):

Post data without json_encode & use form_params instead of body

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();

$response = $client->post('https://www.website.com/oauth/token', [
    'form_params' => [
        'client_id' => 99,
        'client_secret' => '***',
        'grant_type' => 'password',
        'username' => 'username@mail.com',
        'password' => 'password',
        'scope' => '*',
    ],
]);

$auth = json_decode((string) $response->getBody()->getContents());
$data = [
    'first_name' => 'Post', 'last_name' => 'Man',
    'email' => 'postman@mail.com', 'phone' => '0400000000',
    'country' => 'Internet', 'state' => 'HTTP'
];

$header = array('Authorization' => 'Bearer '.$auth->access_token, 'Content-Type' => 'application/json');
$response = $client->post('https://www.website.com/api/store_data',
    ['form_params' => $data, 'headers' => $header]);

$stream = $response->getBody()->getContents();
dd($stream);
```

For store the data:

```
$post = $request->all();

Enquiry::create([
    'first_name' => $post['first_name'],
    'last_name' => $post['last_name']
]);
```